# Return col name for unique value in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to know how can I return the column name for a unique value in a data frame
Like that example:

```
L3 <- LETTERS[1:3]
fac <- sample(L3, 10, replace = TRUE)
(d <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:10, fac = fac))
```

This command just return to me NULL

```
colnames(d[5,2])
```

but the result should be "y"

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure why you would do it this way, but `drop = FALSE` will retain the matrix structure, and hence the names, when subsetting one row/col.  So you can use `colnames(d[5,2, drop=FALSE])`.  But as shown below, `names(d)[2]` seems more appropriate.

Comment: Perfect!! drop=F is what I wanted!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use either `colnames(d[2])` or `colnames(d)[2]` to get the column names.

Answer (score 1):

You have to index a vector that contains the colnames,
try `colnames(d)[2]`